# How do I obtain all of the rowIDs from a select statement?

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

When performing select which returns multiple rows only the last rowID is returned by the function OCIAttrGet.

Is there a way of obtaining the ID of every row which the select statement returned?

Comment: `select rowid, ....`?

Comment: Good point but I need to avoid modifying the select query if possible

Comment: You can't. If you want to return the ROWID you have to select it.

Comment: I believe you can use OCIAttrGet and pass OCI_ATTR_ROWID?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using oracle, you can just

```
select ROWID, your_attribute from your_table
```

This statement selects the address of all rows that contain data for employees in department 20:

```
SELECT ROWID, last_name  
   FROM employees
   WHERE department_id = 20;
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way of doing it without changing the select query?

Comment: i don't get the "without changing the select query". You have to modify the existing query, or you have to do another query. I might miss something here..

Comment: It is a little awkward.  The query is built and in a complicated section of code, I need to update all of the rows at once and was hoping to do so without opening the can of worms that is the selet code.  It looks like it cannot be done though :-(